# Gradle always skips Copy task

Tags: gradle

I've got a directory structure like so:

```
./
    bar/
    build.gradle
    foo/
        asdf.txt
```

The contents of build.gradle are:

```
task qwer(type: Copy) << {
    def from_dir = "foo"
    def dest_dir = "bar"
    println "From: " + from_dir
    println "To: " + dest_dir
    from(from_dir)
    into(dest_dir)
    include "*.txt"
}
```

When I execute `gradle qwer` from in that top directory, gradle prints out that the `:qwer` task is up to date and that the build was successful, but `bar/` remains empty, and those two `println` commands never seem to have printed anything.

After adding the `--info` switch, gradle reports this:

```
Skipping task ':qwer' as it has no source files.
```

I've tried changing it to include `"*"` or `"asdf.txt"`, and I've tried dropping the include line altogether, all with the same results.

This is with Gradle 2.13 on Kubuntu 14.04 with Java 1.8.0_66 and Groovy 1.4.4.

So what do I need to do to get gradle to actually copy files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me with Gradle 2.12. The `<<` in the original is a problem, as we don't want *doLast* behaviour in this case (we want to define the Task):

```
task qwer(type: Copy) {
    def from_dir = "foo"
    def dest_dir = "bar"
    println "From: " + from_dir
    println "To: " + dest_dir
    from(from_dir)
    into(dest_dir)
    include "*.txt"
}
```